# Как реализовать эквивалент пустого массива MongoDB с помощью нативного драйвера Golang?

Tags: golang, mongodb, mongodb-query

Пытаюсь реализовать запрос к MongoBD который является эквивалентом:

```
ME.find({ pictures: { $exists: true, $ne: [] } })
```

Подскажите как это сделать c помощью bson типов официального драйвера mongo-go-driver? Нужно что-то типа:

```
collection.find(bson.M{"pictures":  bson.M{"$exists": true, "$ne": "[]"}},)
```

где **"[]"** - искомый bson

Comment: Пробовали `bson.A{}`?

Comment: Работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте пустой [`bson.A`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#A):

```golang
"$ne": bson.A{},
```